# Jetpack Navigation Using Nested Navigation Graphs Error

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-jetpack-navigation

I have implemented jetpack navigation in an app with a single activity. The navigation is composed of several nested navigation graphs. To put this into context, let's say I have a parent activity A that has a `FragmentContainerView` that has its own navigation graph. Within this `Activity` A, I have a `Fragment` B that has its own navigation graph that is connected to a `BottomNavigationView` within the fragment. When I do this the `app:startDestination` set for Fragment B's navigation graph is inflated in `Activity` A's `FragmentContainerView` without showing `Fragment` B.

Now my question is can you implement a jetpack navigation graph with nested graphs inside `FragmentContainerViews` of `Fragments`?

Comment: You can add the FragmentB's navigation graph to the first navGraph , read the official doc - https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/design/nested-graphs. If this doesn't solves your problem then share your xml code so that we can get more clarity,